# What term describes procedural/fractal generation where coordinates are generated without knowledge of other coordinates?

Tags: algorithm, terminology, fractals, procedural-generation

Both Cellular Automata and Midpoint Displacement rely on information about the grid itself as it's being generated to be able to finish the generation process. Perlin/Simplex Noise are the only methods I'm aware of that generate the data for any given location using a predetermined map in such a way that any coordinate could be calculated without knowledge of other coordinates.

Is there a term for this difference I'm trying to describe? Something hopefully searchable?

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a term for this. May I suggest ***neighbourhood independent*** ?

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for "Context-Free"?